# How do I use Interactivity:Interaction.Triggers on DatePicker

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am trying to bind SelectedDateChanged to a command so I can place it inside my ViewModel but nomatter what then it wont accept this code

http://pastebin.com/T4q8hQBA

```
<DatePicker Name="HistoryDateTime" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" DisplayDateStart="{Binding Path=StartDate}" DisplayDateEnd="{Binding Path=EndDate}" SelectedDate="{Binding Path=SelectedDate}" >
<Interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
<Interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedDateChanged" >
<Helpers:InvokeDelegateCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.SaveKategorieCommand, ElementName=LayoutRoot}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
</Interactivity:EventTrigger>
</DatePicker>
```

I know line 4 is wrong but even with that removed none of those lines are accepted, so do I need to include a file or something for Interactivity to work?

This is C# and WPF not silverlight btw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to add to your namespace declaration the following one:

```
xmlns:interactivity="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

And add a reference to `System.Windows.Interactivity` to your project.

Comment: So its not part of the standard library if I have to download a dll file? (To add it as a reference)

Comment: it is part of Blend. Have a look here:http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/en/blend/thread/8523aec4-1a10-4864-8ad4-f95a3627bb4a, I suppose it is redistributable since you can find it in caliburn for example

Comment: guess I need to download Expression first then

Comment: I cant seem to add it as a reference, I downloaded the caliburn but if I go to browse it is not shown and if I copypaste it into C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0 then its not shown in the .NET either

Answer (score 0):

For Windows-8.1 application development we should add below line

```
xmlns:interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
```