# TreeView - binding to IsExpanded property

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, mvvm-light

I have a TreeView declared as follows:

```
<TreeView Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" DockPanel.Dock="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SomeBinding, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.DoSmth, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                                                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TreeView}}}"/>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SomeOtherBinding}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Unfortunately this binding doesn't work and DoSmth isn't being called.

EDIT

I added this code, but it also won't work:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="TreeViewItem.Expanded">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.DoSmth}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeView}}}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

EDIT

I want to bind to `TreeViewItem` and I thought that I'm doing so on both code snippets. I also want to be able to run `DoSmth` command if any of those items will be expanded

Comment: Not sure I understand what you want to achieve but `IsExpanded` is `bool` property not an event or command

Comment: So what is the other way to run my `DoSmth` command when `TreeViewItem` is expanded?

Comment: You're looking for `TreeViewItem.Expanded` event and check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754410/how-do-i-use-interactivityinteraction-triggers-on-datepicker) question

Comment: It should be `Command="{Binding Path=DoSmth}"` instead of `Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.DoSmth}"` unless your view model has `DataContext` property. Your view model is context here. Not `TreeViewItem`

Comment: I tried this with every combination and it still doesn't work...

Comment: What is the scenario here? Why are you binding to the `TreeView` and not the `TreeViewItem`? Do you want to `expand` all the children of a `TreeViewItem`? Or what? Your question is not enough without enough context

Comment: I want to bind to TreeViewItem and I thought that I'm doing so on both code snippets. I also want to be able to run DoSmth command if any of those items will be expanded.